# Magento 2 uiComponent view model

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have a **uiComponent** defined

```
define(
    ['jquery', 'ko', 'uiComponent', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal', 'domReady!'],
    function($, ko, Component, modal) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this._super();

                //get view model here   
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I have a couple of questions:

**1.** Is the Magento2 **uiComponent** a knockout component ?

**2.** Does this basic component has a view model created and attached to it on Component.extend ?

**3.** If the view model does not exist how do we add it to the component (better to have it in writing if that is the case) ?

**4.** How can I get the component view model in the initialize method ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. The js code you posted *is* the component view model, the component also needs a template. In your view model we can add any logic or data to be used in the template. For example, let's add an observable:

   ```
   return Component.extend({
       value: ko.observable('Hello world'),
       initialize: function() {
           this._super();
       }
   });
   ```
3. As stated, your view model already exists but you need to create your component template. This is a simple html file which can use knockout methods and any logic defined in your view model:

`<span data-bind="text: value"></span>`

To initialize your component (view model and template) you can do so in a phtml file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": ”Vendor_Module/js/example-view”,
                    "template": "Vendor_Module/template/example-template”
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Which will render your your component:

`<span>Hello world</span>`

Components can also be initialized in xml, see for example `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`